# Why Saturn has more Moons than Jupiter?

Tags: jupiter, natural-satellites, saturn

Why does Saturn have more moons than Jupiter, I know the grand tack hypothesis suggests Jupiter migrated from 3.5 au to present orbit but given that Jupitern is more massive meaning a larger hillsphere and closer to the asteroid belt and inner solar system, with multiple minor bodies to be captured. I know many moons remain undetected but can anybody please give explanation for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: See: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13419/why-does-the-planet-saturn-have-numerous-62-moons-compared-to-the-rest-of-the (Yes, this post needs recent update)

Comment: That is a direct duplicate, but Ias Nilay said, the answer could be updated.  You could set a bounty on that question to encourage someone to refresh the answer.

Comment: @NilayGhosh Thanks for the link! It answers my questions partially

Comment: @JamesK Thanks a lot! The answer really helped me answer the question partially, I will try to use the bounty too. But I have a doubt, Is ice the only reason it has more moons, what other factors influence it?. thanks again

Comment: @JamesK bounty done

Comment: Also https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/36356/why-isnt-there-a-large-gap-in-the-number-of-captured-moons-jupiter-and-saturn-h (again, this also needs update)

Comment: The title asks "Why Saturn has more Moons than Jupiter?" while the body asks "Why does Jupiter have more moons than Saturn?" Which are you asking? BTW, it appears that Saturn has more moons than Jupiter. This might just be observational bias, but then again, it might be real.

Comment: @DavidHammen Oh, Sorry, my mistake, I accidentally did a typo. Thank you for pointing it out